# Android layout: center and align to the bottom text view

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, centering

I would need to align the reset button to the bottom and center it. Here is the layout:
[image: Android layout]

here is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team B" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
            android:text="Free throw" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="ResetTeamAandB"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is my parent layout is `linear` in the `horizontal` orientation and it adds the `button` in the third column. That is why I am trying to nest it in the `relative` layout and align it somehow. Any ideas would be very much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an alternative solution and it works well. I wrap everything in the relative layout, so my horizontal linear layout is positioned at the top and then the button positioned at the bottom of the relative layout. Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team B" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
            android:text="Free throw" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="ResetTeamAandB"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Team A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
                android:text="Free throw" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Team B" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
                android:text="Free throw" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></View>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="ResetTeamAandB"
        android:text="Reset" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. It work for me! However I am wondering if this is a good practise to add an empty view? could be any other way to achieve it? just asking as I'm a newbie to Android:)

Comment: you have to use View in linear layout in such conditions as above, there is nothing wrong in it. Glade it resolved your problem :)

Comment: using weight everywhere isn't a good practice.  UI need to be calculated with each view which puts extra load.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you were looking for, this should do the trick! This will keep the three columns and put the 'Reset' button at the bottom of the second column.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linear1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Team A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
        android:text="+3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
        android:text="+2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
        android:text="Free throw" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Team B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
        android:text="+3 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
        android:text="+2 Points" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
        android:text="Free throw" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ResetTeamAandB"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for this. however i do not need 3 columns, but 2 and the reset at the very bottom and centered

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add extra LinearLayout to separate views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team B" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
            android:text="+3 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
            android:text="+2 Points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
            android:text="Free throw" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="ResetTeamAandB"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```